# WindowsPhone PhoneCamera - Exception at page resume

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, aggregateexception

I have a strange exception. I use the PhoneCamera API in a page, that the user can make some phothos, which are directly uploaded after the capture.

My Code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    _mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();

    // Initialize the camera object
    _phoneCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    _phoneCamera.Initialized += CamInitialized;
    _phoneCamera.AutoFocusCompleted += PhoneCamera_AutoFocusCompleted;
    _phoneCamera.CaptureImageAvailable += PhoneCamera_CaptureImageAvailable;

    // Display the camera feed in the UI
    ViewfinderBrush.SetSource(_phoneCamera);

    // Rotation for transform
    ViewfinderTransform.Rotation = _phoneCamera.Orientation;
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_phoneCamera != null)
    {
        // Cleanup
        _phoneCamera.Dispose();
        _phoneCamera.Initialized -= CamInitialized;
        _phoneCamera.AutoFocusCompleted -= PhoneCamera_AutoFocusCompleted;
        _phoneCamera.CaptureImageAvailable -= PhoneCamera_CaptureImageAvailable;

        if (_cameraInizialized)
        {
            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed -= CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;
            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed -= CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}

private void CamInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Succeeded)
    {
        // Set flashmode
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {  _phoneCamera.FlashMode = FlashMode.Auto; });

        // Subscribe to hardeware-button-events
        CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;
        CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed;

        _cameraInizialized = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Show error message
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, when the initialized-Event is fired. But i got an exception when the user tapped the home-button of the phone, while the camera is initializing. (initialized-Event not fired).

When the user comes back with the Back-Button, following Exception occurd:

```
[Type]:[AggregateException]
[ExceptionMessage]:[One or more errors occurred.]
[StackTrace]:[
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.OpenCaptureDevice()
    at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeVideoSession>b__0()]
[InnerExceptions]:[[[Type]:[InvalidOperationException]
    [Message]:[The text associated with this error code could not be found.
    Unable to acquire the camera. You can only use this class while in the foreground.]
```

I have tryed many other options, but nothing works. I dont now why this error occurd. Although I know where it occurs, and at which situation.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: There is a known app crash bug with PhoneCamera. The application will crash while navigating back from the camera page when it is not initialized.You can refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/2d600f86-e98f-4a9d-b777-3bb558fd278f/photocamera-inner-task-exception